# MySQL - Use subquery result in another subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am using the following tables for my query:

**customer**

```
id  | name   | lastname
---------------------------------
 1  | john   | text
 2  | rock   | text
 3  | jane   | text
 4  | jack   | text
```

**order_**

```
id_order | customer_id | ...
---------------------------------
 1       |      1      | ...
 2       |      2      | ...
 3       |      3      | ...
 4       |      1      | ...
 5       |      2      | ...
```

I want to implement a query to show the firstname and lastname of the customer with the maximum number of orders. If two or more customers have the same maximum number of orders I want to be shown.

So far I have accomplished the following subqueries:

```
SELECT name, lastname FROM customer
WHERE customer.id IN 
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT order_.customer_id FROM order_
                INNER JOIN customer
                WHERE order_.customer_id = customer.id
                GROUP BY order_.customer_id
                ) temp
)
```

I guess I have to use the MAX function of the last subquery to get the result, I just do not know how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
SELECT c.name, c.lastname, count(o.id_order) 
FROM order_ o INNER JOIN 
     customer c
     on o.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.name, c.lastname
ORDER BY count(o.id_order) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yes and I want to select the MAX count of the above query.

Comment: I can't use 'LIMIT 1', because as I have mentioned, I want if two or more customers have the same max number of orders, I want all to be shown

Comment: @Strawberry Yes this  is not what I want

Comment: @BeginnerProg Although, of course, in this instance all customers have the same number of orders.

Comment: @Strawberry For this instance yes, but I want it for general

Comment: For next time, may I suggest you provide a more representative data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE customers;

CREATE TABLE customers
(customer_id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,lastname VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customers VALUES
(1,'john','text'),
(2,'rock','text'),
(3,'jane','text');

DROP TABLE orders;

CREATE TABLE orders
(order_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,customer_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3);


SELECT a.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT c.*
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM customers c
         JOIN orders o
           ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
        GROUP 
           BY customer_id
    ) a
 JOIN   
    ( SELECT MAX(x.total) max_total
        FROM 
           ( SELECT customer_id
                  , COUNT(*) total 
               FROM orders 
              GROUP 
                 BY customer_id
           ) x
   ) b
  ON b.max_total = a.total;

+-------------+------+----------+-------+
| customer_id | name | lastname | total |
+-------------+------+----------+-------+
|           1 | john | text     |     1 |
|           2 | rock | text     |     1 |
|           3 | jane | text     |     1 |
+-------------+------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.id as 'id',c.name as 'name',c.lastname as 'lastname',count(o.id_order) as 'total_orders'
 from customer c
 inner join order_ o
 ON c.id = o.customer_id
 group by c.id
 having total_orders = (select max(orders)
 from (select count(o1.id_order) as 'orders'
       from customer c1
       inner join order_ o1
        ON c1.id = o1.customer_id
        group by c1.id) derived)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more complicated because you want duplicates.  Assuming that `customer_id` defines a customer and not the names, you can do:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.lastname
from customer c join
     order_ o
     on o.customer_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.name, c.lastname
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from order_ o2
                   group by o2.customer_id
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

Note that the subquery in the `having` clause does not require a `join` back to `customer` -- assuming that the `id` is the appropriate definition of a customer.